# Backup to remote win machine

Tags: 10.04, samba, rsync

I have to backup my data to a remote machine. The local machine run ubuntu 10.04 and the remote machine run winXP.

Googling I found several discussion about this argument but none of them helps me to solve this problem.

This is what I've done:

1) create a mounting point for the remote folder

```
 sudo mkdir /mnt/backup
```

2) mount the remote folder

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=XXX,password=XXXX //10.1.1.111/maxquant_linux /mnt/backup
```

3) Perform rsync

```
sudo rsync -avz /home/cism/Documents/Data/ /mnt/backup/
```

This is the error I obtained:

```
sending incremental file list
./

rsync: failed to set times on "/mnt/backup/.": Permission denied (13)
2012/

rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/mnt/backup/2012" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
2013/

rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/mnt/backup/2013" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***

sent 57568 bytes  received 304 bytes  38581.33 bytes/sec

total size is 36670901857  speedup is 633655.34

rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1060) [sender=3.0.7]
```

I have tried several rsync options such as

```
--rsync-path='/usr/bin/rsync'
```

and

```
--rsync-path="sudo rsync"
```

but I obtain always the same kind of errors.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem. Although you mounted the remote directory, it appears you do not have permission. I am not sure from what you posted if this is a problem with configuration from windows or Ubuntu. What is the output of `ls -l /mnt/backup`

Comment: I try the `ls -l` command and I found two different results. Before the mount I obtain  `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2013-02-28 11:57 backup` and after the mount command I obtain `drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 2013-02-23 23:41 backup`.